# NodeJs AES File Decryption to a Stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, pipe, nodejs-stream

I am encrypting a file in C# and decrypting it in Node.js using AES.
The following example works fine but it writes the decrypted file to `output_dec.xml', but I want to write the decrypted output to a variable or stream.

```js
const crypto = require("crypto");
const fs = require('fs');

try {

    const password = "McQfTjWnZr4u7x!A";
    const KEY = Buffer.from(password, "utf8");
    const IV = Buffer.from(password, "utf8");

    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', KEY, IV);
    var input = fs.createReadStream(file);
    var output = fs.createWriteStream("output_dec.xml");
    input.pipe(decipher).pipe(output);

    output.on('finish', function () {
        console.log('Decrypted file written to disk!');
    });
}
catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to use it for two cases:

- Output it to another stream. In which case simply replace `.pipe(output)` with `.pipe(anotherStream)`.
- Output to a variable. In which case you can read the data from `input.pipe(decipher)` like this:

```js
const crypto = require("crypto");
const fs = require('fs');

try {

    const password = "McQfTjWnZr4u7x!A";
    const KEY = Buffer.from(password, "utf8");
    const IV = Buffer.from(password, "utf8");

    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', KEY, IV);
    var input = fs.createReadStream(file);
    const deciphered = input.pipe(decipher);
    let data = '';
    deciphered.on('data', chunk => data += chunk);
    deciphered.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Decrypted file stored in data!');
        // Decrypted file in `data`
    });
    deciphered.on('error', (e) => {
        console.error('Error:', e);
    });
    // Can't use `data` here yet (need to wait for 'end' event)
}
catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Kelvin, it worked like a charm. Yes I have to use it for two cases.

Comment: @aadi1295 Then don't forget to mark this answer as the solution to your question.

Comment: Yes waiting for the time limit, it says I can mark the answer in 1 minute.